# How to use a SELECT query along with other fields IN mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using a SELECT query to FETCH results which has some joins, in the result i want a dynamic SELECT query which fetch the name from a table. How to include that SELECT query. For eg, SELECT id, cost , name(this name should be FETCH FROM a table based on some condition so how to include this query.)

Comment: Your question is how to make the column-name of a table dynamic in an SQL-select-statement?

Answer (score 0):

There should be some relationship between the two tables and you can easily use a join `SELECT table1.id, table1.cost, table2.name
JOIN table2 ON table1.field= table2.field
WHERE table2.field = some_condition`

Comment: i am already joining it but the problem is i want to display a particular column which will be different users say displayName but as i am joining for every result it will give me the same display name. But i want different displayName based on the userId

Comment: i am already joining it but the problem is i want to display a particular column which will be different users say displayName but as i am joining for every result it will give me the same display name. But i want different displayName based on the userId

Comment: Show me your query please

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t1.field1, t1.field2, 
(SELECT t2.displayName FROM   tableName t2 JOIN tableName t1 ON t2.field = t1.field) FROM tableName t1 
JOIN tableName t2  WHERE t2.userId=